# Repeat the day of the week for each time inside a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with just one column and about 3000 rows that follows the same pattern. I want to include the days of the week at the beginning of the string for each TIME inside the same string in the row.

Original table :

| DATA_TIME_COMBINATION |
| --- |
| Monday 3 am HM, 5 am HC, 10 pm HX |
| Saturday AB 6 am, WE 5 pm |
| Sunday Friday AN 50 TU,FG 55 RE, DC 56 JJ |
| Tuesday 10 am, 5 am, 1 am |
| Wednesday 12 pm-9 pm- 1 am |

Results needed :

| DATA_TIME_COMBINATION |
| --- |
| Monday 3 am HM, Monday 5 am HC, Monday 10 pm HX |
| Saturday AB 6 am, Saturday WE 5 pm |
| Sunday Friday AN 50 TU, Sunday Friday FG 55 RE, Sunday Friday DC 56 JJ |
| Tuesday 10 am, Tuesday 5 am, Tuesday 1 am |
| Wednesday 12 pm- Wednesday 9 pm- Wednesday 1 am |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried to bring the times to a separated row by first creating an identity row on mytable using : ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD ID INT IDENTITY

Comment: Then I move the TIMEs after the comma to another row by using :             SELECT s.ID, f.value
  FROM mytable AS s
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s.[DATA_TIME_COMBINATION], ',') as f;

Comment: [edit] any clarifications into your question

Comment: Can you describe the problem _precisely_, i.e. what is a time? Is it one or two digits, an optional space, and "AM" or "PM" (case-insensitive)? Never "noon", "8:15", "20:15", "7PST", "sunset", "1 pm resigned", ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you want replace the comma with a comma and the first word at beginning of the string

```
select replace(DATA_TIME_COMBINATION, ',', 
    concat(',', substr(DATA_TIME_COMBINATION,1,charindex(' ', DATA_TIME_COMBINATION)-1)))
from my_table
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you!  The only problem with this solution is that it will only pick the first day for each row. For example row3 has 'Sunday Friday', which has to be repeated like this: 'Sunday Friday AN 50 TU, Sunday Friday FG 55 RE, Sunday Friday DC 56 JJ'. This solution will only pick 'Sunday' to be repeated like this : 'Sunday AN 50 TU, Sunday FG 55 RE, Sunday DC 56 JJ'. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the character and days.

Then it'll become a simple replace.

One cross apply for the weekdays.

A second for a character in place.

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(REPLACE([DATA_TIME_COMBINATION], chr, chr+' '+days+' '),'  ',' ') as DATA_TIME_COMBINATION
FROM mytable AS t
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(value, ' ') days
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(
  LEFT([DATA_TIME_COMBINATION], PATINDEX('%[a-z] [0-9]%', [DATA_TIME_COMBINATION])), ' ') spl
  WHERE value LIKE '%day'
) ca1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT 
   chr = SUBSTRING([DATA_TIME_COMBINATION], PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9 ]%', [DATA_TIME_COMBINATION]), 1)
) ca2;
```

| DATA_TIME_COMBINATION |
| --- |
| Monday 3 am HM, Monday 5 am HC, Monday 10 pm HX |
| Saturday AB 6 am, Saturday WE 5 pm |
| Sunday Friday AN 50 TU, Sunday Friday FG 55 RE, Sunday Friday DC 56 JJ |
| Tuesday 10 am, Tuesday 5 am, Tuesday 1 am |
| Wednesday 12 pm- Wednesday 9 pm- Wednesday 1am |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5bce085839483c787763fab7366963c9)*